# Reading TCP packet buffer

Tags: sockets, tcp, buffer

To receive data through TCP, I need to set a buffer with a default size, if the size of the packet I received is greater than this buffer, so I need to loop until finish reading all the bytes sent. Example, if I received 4096 bytes and my reader buffer is set to 1024, I need to loop 4 times to get the whole packet?

Each loop, I'm ordering the next 1024 bytes across the connection or the operating system has all 4096 stored in memory and I'm just doing a copy?

Some good article about how it all works in low level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question has a lot to do with the layers below the application layer, but I'll try to answer it as best I can.

Your Network Interface Card (NIC) is performing all of the necessary tasks of collecting packets and waiting for your OS to read them. Ultimately, when you do a stream read you're pulling from the memory that your OS has reserved and constantly stores the incoming information copy into.

To answer your question, yes. You are definitely doing a copy. A copy of a copy, the bits are read into a buffer within your NIC, your OS puts them somewhere, and you copy them when you do a stream read.

I'm not sure of a good article as much as a general course in college-level networking. I'd suggest a book on the subject, but I don't have much experiences with different networking textbooks to make a suggestion for one over another.

Edit: I get the feeling that you want to know the exact code the runs when you perform a stream read. I can't tell if you've specified a language, but here is a link to the C# stream source: [Microsoft Stream.cs source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/stream.cs#f956b0c07e86df64)

Answer (score 3):

The TCP implementation has a receive buffer that is almost certainly larger than 4KB. So the sender isn't waiting for you to receive the first 1KB before it sends the second 1KB. Receiving with small buffers only results in extra calls into the TCP layer.

Sending with small buffers, however, can result in "short packets" being sent and resulting inefficiencies due to delayed ACK and Nagling. For TCP over typical Ethernet and Internet networks, 2KB is a minimal sane send buffer (because it's larger than the common MTU), but 8KB or more is advisable.